# Get Time Difference between GMT and local time in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to get the difference in seconds in GMT time and Local time but i am unable to get using `System.currentTimeMillis()`

GMT: Wed, 15 Apr 2015 14:54:39 GMT

Your time zone: 4/15/2015, 8:24:39 PM GMT+5:30 (Asia/Calcutta)

What i need is the timestamps in milliseconds or seconds of the GMT time and my local time so that i can calculate their difference's

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you may over-thinking your problem.

You can get an object representing the current Time Zone by:

```
TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getDefault();
```

And then, use the [`getRawOffset()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getRawOffset()) method, that returns the number of milliseconds that timezone is offset from UTC (which is equivalent to GMT).

```
timezone.getRawOffset();
```

Doing a calculation is over-kill.

Comment: this method is returning 0 for me and my local time is 5:30 ahead of GMT

Comment: @RahulGupta what does `TimeZone.getDefault()` return for you?

Comment: You might want to consider using TimeZone.getOffset() instead, which takes daylight savings time into account.

Answer (score 1):

@Rahul Gupta, once you have obtained the Date object from the above dates, you can use

```
Date.getTime()
```

to get the milliseconds equivalent.
You can refer this as well
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Comment: While not incorrect, this returns the absolute time, in milliseconds since Epoch. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57220021/2102748

Answer (score 1):

Difference has been defined by the GMT code, 
if your GMT is +/- 5.30 ,

then difference is = 5 * 60 *60 + 30 * 60 seconds